# How to test an onboarding?

Tags: usability-testing, onboarding

I have to test an onboarding, and I'm pretty blocked because I'm running out of ideas for tasks for the testing.

It's an onboarding of 12  steps showing the product and showing step by step how to use it.

I thought to let users go through it and then ask them to perform some of the tasks explained previously to see if it was clear.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Any more information on what type of product it is and the types of users that will be using this product?

Comment: Sorry, It's a new feature for our product, wich is a low code platform for developing apps, our users are internal employees wich uses the platform themself

Answer (score 2):

I would focus more on the onboarding part. Creating a natural scenario "you want to sign up on this app because a friend suggested it to you - can you please do that"

then check:

- how are they clicking through it?
- are they reading the text?
- some steps that are of more interest than others?
- to the user get stuck somewhere?
- how long time does it take?

if you want to try out some tasks thats in onboarding, try to make it as natural as possible, don't make it seem like you are testing out the onboarding steps (i.e taking very specific tasks).

In the end - I would have some interview questions - how they perceived the onboarding, how they would continue to use the product, and if they have any questions further on how to use the product.